# How to solve $\ln (v+\sqrt{1+v^2})=-k\ln(x)+k\ln(a)$ for $v$ in terms of $x$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Consider the differential equation

$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{y}{x}-k\sqrt{1+\frac{y^2}{x^2}}$$

We can utilize the substitution $v=\frac{y}{x}$ to solve this equation for $y(x)$.

$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{dv}{dx}x+v=v-k\sqrt{1+v^2}$$
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+v^2}}dv=-\frac{k}{x}dx$$
$$ln (v+\sqrt{1+v^2})=-kln(x)+C$$

Assume $y(a)=0$ is the initial condition. Then $v(a)=\frac{y(a)}{x}=0$ and $C=kln(a)$
$$ln (v+\sqrt{1+v^2})=-kln(x)+kln(a)$$

We need to solve this for $v$ in terms of x, then we can substitute in $v=\frac{y}{x}$ to obtain $y(x)$, the solution the original differential equation.

**The question is, how does one solve for $v$ here?**

This is all from an example in a differential equations textbook. To be exact, it is chapter 1.6 (Substitution Methods and Exact Equations) of Edwards/Penney's Elementary Differential Equations, 6th edition. The differential equation here is from a problem on calculating a flight trajectory. The example doesn't show the passage that this question is about; it is rather given as an end-of-chapter problem, but I don't have solutions

Comment: Take sinh of both sides. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_hyperbolic_functions#Inverse_hyperbolic_sine

Comment: $k ln(a) - k ln(x) = ln((a/x)^{k})$

Answer (score 2):

Using  [@Lac](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/833003/lac)'s comment, we have $$\ln(v+\sqrt{1+v^2})=\ln\left(\left(\frac{a}{x}\right)^k\right)$$
$$\Rightarrow v+\sqrt{1+v^2}=\left(\frac{a}{x}\right)^k \tag{1}$$

From the identity $a^2-b^2=(a-b)(a+b)$, we have $$\Rightarrow a-b=\frac{a^2-b^2}{a+b}$$ where $a\neq b$.

So, we can set $a=\sqrt{1+v^2}, b=v$ and obtain $$\sqrt{1+v^2}-v=\frac{\left(\sqrt{1+v^2}\right)^2-v^2}{\sqrt{1+v^2}+v}$$
$$\Rightarrow \sqrt{1+v^2}-v=\left(\frac xa\right)^k \tag{2}$$

Now you can add (or subtract) $(1)$ and $(2)$ and solve for $v$.

Answer (score 2):

The better antiderivative to use is

$$\frac{dv}{\sqrt{1+v^2}} = -\frac{k}{x}dx \implies \sinh^{-1}v = -k \ln |x| + C$$

which means

$$y = x \sinh \left(k\ln\left|\frac{a}{x}\right|\right)$$

or

$$y = \frac{a^k}{2}x^{1-k}-\frac{a^{-k}}{2}x^{1+k}$$

for $x>0$

Answer (score 0):

It is a simple algebraic simplification.
$$\log[\sqrt{1+v^2}+v]=\log (a/x)^k$$
$$\implies [\sqrt{1+v^2}+v]=(x/a)^k$$
$$\implies [\sqrt{1+v^2}-v]=(a/x)^k$$
Subtract the two to get
$$v=\frac{1}{2}[(x/a)^k-(a/x)^k]$$